# Emacs: keep region selected after operation

Tags: emacs

In emacs, after an operation such as `comment-region`, the selected region is automatically deselected.

Is there any way of disabling this behaviour?

Comment: Are you sure the region is deselected, or you just lost the visual highlight? (You may try running `uncomment-region` right after `comment-region`.)

Comment: Wow, you are right, thanks!  I'll accept Brians' answer.

Comment: 4 years later and I have completely forgotten that the region is still invisibly selected. I gotta find a text editor with a better UI.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the region is deselected, that sounds like you must be using [`transient-mark-mode`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/emacs.html#Transient-Mark). In `transient-mark-mode`, when you execute a command that operates on the region, the region is deselected (in particular, the mark remains, but it is inactive). You can reselect the region (reactivate the mark) using `C-x C-x` (`exchange-point-and-mark`).

If you want to disable the deselection entirely, you can turn off `transient-mark-mode`. This means that you won't get any highlighting of the current region, though if you would like to set the mark and highlight the region, you can [turn on transient mark mode briefly](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/emacs.html#Momentary-Mark) using `C-<SPC> C-<SPC>` or `C-u C-x C-x`.

Comment: hmm, I can't seem to turn it off - I now have 
(custom-set-variables
 '(transient-mark-mode nil))
in .emacs
and M-x transient-mark-mode gives:
Transient-Mark mode disabled

but the behaviour (highlighting & immediate deselection) hasn't changed

Comment: That's rather odd. Do you have something else in your .emacs that enables transient mark mode? Or is there something in a particular major mode you're using that forces transient mark mode on?

Comment: grep -r "transient" ~/.emacs.d/ turns up nothing, and nothing in ~/.emacs

Comment: slink pointed me towards the answer - with transient-mark-mode off, the behaviour doesn't seem to have changed (still a 'transient' highlighting of region), but the region does seem to be permanent.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. It doesn't work that way in my version of Emacs; I'm running GNU Emacs 22.3, perhaps you're running a different version? Glad you got it working, anyhow.

Answer (score 2):

Make use of the variable `deactivate-mark`:

```lisp
(defun acg/with-mark-active (&rest args)
  "Keep mark active after command. To be used as advice AFTER any
function that sets `deactivate-mark' to t."
  (setq deactivate-mark nil))

(advice-add 'comment-region :after #'acg/with-mark-active)
```

In the example above, you can replace `comment-region` with any other function you desire.

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately, Keyboard macros don't deselect the region if they alter it.  So you can write your function, then create a kbd macro that calls your function and then does C-x C-x once or, if you care about point and mark being as they were, do it twice.  Then name your kbd macro.  Then M-x write-kbd-macro  and, when prompted, give it the name of the file that you want the macro appended to and then give it the name of your new macro.  If you now bind your macro to a key you can repeatedly press the key without losing the region. 
   It would sure be nice if  Emacs's 'interactive' took '_' as part of the string argument to retain the region and highlighting the way XEmacs's 'interactive' does.