# conf/ini files indentation Emacs

Tags: emacs, configuration-files, indentation, ini

so here is my problem:
.conf files(like smb.conf and xorg.conf) should look something like this

```
[some-header]
    somevar = someval
    othervar = otherval
[other header]
    opt1 = pref1
    opt2 = pref2
```

what emacs basically does when i "indent-region" is something like this(depending on the current indentation)

```
    [some-header]
        somevar = someval
            othervar = otherval
                [other header]
                    opt1 = pref1
                        opt2 = pref2
```

how do i fix this?

Comment: I am getting bit opposite results though. all the lines comes to first column with zero inendation.

Comment: I've detailed the reason for that staircase effect in a different answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3278026/emacs-remember-text-selection/3281811#3281811